# pylab.show() forgets previous plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to make pylab.show() non-forgetting ?

By this , I mean something like following:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
pylab.plot(x, y)
pylab.show()
```

[image]

Now on typing,

```
 pylab.ylim(-1.5, 2.0)
 pylab.show()
```

I get thje following figure
[image]

Is it possible to get the original figure with the ylimits changed (for the sake of this example) without using `pylab.plot(x, y)` again ?

I have given a very simple example, but it becomes really tedious to retype everything in the actual cases.

(I want a generalized answer wherein pylab.show() remembers the previous figure it plotted )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `pylab.ion()` to turn on [interactive mode](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-interactive-mode).  The figure will automatically update.

```
pylab.ion()
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
pylab.plot(x, y)
```

Then when you call

```
pylab.ylim(-1.5, 2.0)
```

The figure will automatically update.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen that a new figure is being created. To avoid this you should get the current axis first and then set the new limits:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
ax = pylab.gca()
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.set_ylim(-1.5, 2.0)
ax.figure.show()
```

Comment: No, it's not working, can you show with an example ?. I might be wrong.

Comment: thank you, it worked, can you please tell me why it was not working last time.

Comment: @the first `pylab.show()` creates a new figure which is different from the one obtained with `ax=pylab.gca(); ax.figure.show()`, and therefore the second figure appears blank

Comment: This is for beginners like me : after making any change to the figure, you'll have to do `ax.figure.show()` to see the change (don't do pylab.show() as pointed out by Saullo) where as if you use in interactive mode, as soon as you make any change, the figure gets updated